# Maven release build fails in Jenkins due to failure to build a release version of dependency

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, ear, maven-release-plugin

Maven release build of EAR app fails due to failure of MODULE 2 to find a release version of MODULE 1.

**Maven version** is 2.2.1.
**Maven command**:
--batch-mode release:prepare release:perform  -DdryRun=false -Darguments='-Dmaven.test.skip=true' -e

**Excerpt from log:**

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Building MODULE 1
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/jenkins/workspace/repo-trunk-release/target/checkout/module-1-trunk-release/src/main/resources
[INFO] [INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] [INFO] Compiling 120 source files to /home/jenkins/workspace/repo-trunk-release/target/checkout/module-1-trunk-release/target/classes
[INFO] [WARNING] /home/jenkins/workspace/repo-trunk-release/target/checkout/module-1-trunk-release/src/main/java/com/.../SomeClass.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[INFO] [WARNING] /home/jenkins/workspace/repo-trunk-release/target/checkout/module-1-trunk-release/src/main/java/com/.../SomeClass.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO] [WARNING] /home/jenkins/workspace/repo-trunk-release/target/checkout/module-1-trunk-release/src/main/java/com/.../SomeClass.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] [WARNING] /home/jenkins/workspace/repo-trunk-release/target/checkout/module-1-trunk-release/src/main/java/com/.../SomeClass.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Building MODULE 2
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] [INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO] Downloading: http:.../nexus/.../module-1-trunk-release/11.0.29/module-1-trunk-release-11.0.29.jar
[INFO] [INFO] Unable to find resource '....apps:module-1-trunk-release:jar:11.0.29' in repository central (http://.../nexus/content/groups/public)
[INFO] Downloading:.http//../nexus/content/repositories/.../module-1-trunk-release/11.0.29/module-1-trunk-release-11.0.29.jar
[INFO] [WARNING] Unable to get resource '....apps:module-1-trunk-release:jar:11.0.29' from repository secondary (http://.../nexus/content/repositories/...-releases): Error transferring file: Connection refused
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.
[INFO] 
[INFO] Missing:
[INFO] ----------
[INFO] 1) ....apps:module-1-trunk-release:jar:11.0.29
[INFO] 
[INFO]   Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[INFO] 
[INFO]   Then, install it using the command: 
[INFO]       mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=....apps -DartifactId=module-1-trunk-release -Dversion=11.0.29 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
[INFO] 
[INFO]   Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
[INFO]       mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=....apps -DartifactId=module-1-trunk-release -Dversion=11.0.29 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[INFO] 
[INFO]   Path to dependency: 
[INFO]      1) ....apps:module-2:jar:11.0.29
[INFO]      2) ....apps:module-1:jar:11.0.29
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------
[INFO] 1 required artifact is missing.
[INFO] 
[INFO] for artifact: 
[INFO]   ....apps:module-2:jar:11.0.29
[INFO] 
[INFO] from the specified remote repositories:
[INFO]   repo-pub1 (http://..../nexus/content/repositories/...-releases),
[INFO]   repo-pub2 (http://..../nexus/content/groups/public)
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 42 seconds
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: Thu Dec 03 17:18:49 GMT 2015
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 99M/438M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:284)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutorInterceptor.execute(LifecycleExecutorInterceptor.java:65)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at hudson.maven.agent.Main.launch(Main.java:205)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuilder.call(MavenBuilder.java:154)
    at hudson.maven.Maven2Builder.call(Maven2Builder.java:79)
    at hudson.maven.Maven2Builder.call(Maven2Builder.java:55)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:120)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PerformReleaseMojo.execute(PerformReleaseMojo.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at hudson.maven.agent.PluginManagerInterceptor.executeMojo(PluginManagerInterceptor.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.ReleaseExecutionException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRunGoalsPhase.execute(AbstractRunGoalsPhase.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.RunPerformGoalsPhase.runLogic(RunPerformGoalsPhase.java:135)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.RunPerformGoalsPhase.execute(RunPerformGoalsPhase.java:46)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.perform(DefaultReleaseManager.java:429)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.perform(DefaultReleaseManager.java:381)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PerformReleaseMojo.execute(PerformReleaseMojo.java:170)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.MavenExecutorException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor.executeGoals(InvokerMavenExecutor.java:433)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.AbstractMavenExecutor.executeGoals(AbstractMavenExecutor.java:114)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRunGoalsPhase.execute(AbstractRunGoalsPhase.java:85)
    ... 35 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2 minutes 27 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Dec 03 17:18:50 GMT 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 33M/404M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[JENKINS] Archiving /home/jenkins/workspace/repo-trunk-release/pom.xml to ....apps/.../11.0.29-SNAPSHOT/repo-trunk-release-11.0.29-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: First i would [leave Maven 2.2.1](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html) furthermore which Version of maven-release-plugin do you use? Apart from that this looks wrong ` Error transferring file: Connection refused

Comment: The maven-release-plugin is 2.5.2. Tried maven 3.3.9 but got different error.

Comment: @khmarbaise the file transfer error has probably more to do with secondary nexus repo having bad config. Normally build would expect to get MODULE 1 from main nexus repo. Dont think that this relates to main issue of release build failing.

Comment: Does the ear module contain module1 and module2 (using like war or similar?)...is this a multi module build? Is there given a correct dependency between the modules?

Comment: @khmarbaise yes it is multi module - EAR with jars for EJBs and it also builds a WAR web app. Version being built in this case is 11.0.29 and MODULE 1 and MODULE 2 should also get built as 11.0.29 based on use of:                                                                                                        
`<dependency>
 <groupId>com.module.one</groupId>
 <artifactId>module-1</artifactId>
 <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>`

Answer (score 4):

Fixed build and this is how. 
I first switched to maven 3.0.2 in the Jenkins config, since as alluded to by 
@khmarbaise using maven 2.2.1 was the root of issue.

But then I got wsimport errors, to fix these I removed the encoding property

```
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
```

from the parent pom.

I then got a lot of encoding errors, of the type,

```
error: unmappable character for encoding ANSI_X3.4-1968
```

so to fix these I added

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

to the the to MAVEN OPTS props in the Jenkins job config.

The encoding errors were related to the existence of lots of 'strange' chars in JavaDoc and elsewhere in app code.